# Google Ad word download the report using python Console

Tags: python, csv, google-ads-api

this is my code when I am trying to run it I am getting this error in the console.

```
path = 'MYpaath'
    report_downloader = client.GetReportDownloader(version='v201309')

    # Create report definition.
    report = {
              'reportName': 'Last 7 days CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT',
              'dateRangeType': 'LAST_7_DAYS',
              'reportType': 'CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT',
              'downloadFormat': 'CSV',
              'selector': {
                           'fields': ['CampaignId', 'AdGroupId', 'Id', 'CriteriaType',
                 'Criteria', 'Impressions', 'Clicks', 'Cost']
                           },
  # Enable to get rows with zero impressions.
  'includeZeroImpressions': 'false'
    }
    print("============================================",report)
    file1= report_downloader.DownloadReport(report, file_path=path)
    print 'Report was downloaded to \'%s\'.' % file1
```

Error I am Getting after running this

```
file= report_downloader.DownloadReport(report, file_path=path)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\adspygoogle-1.1.4-py2.7.egg\adspygoogle\adwords\ReportDownloader.py", line 100, in DownloadReport
fileobj = open(file_path, 'w')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or 
filename:'MYpath'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar error and it was associated with the path and the way you open the file and write to it. Set your path to the following:

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)),"temp","report.csv")
```

This basically sets the path to: /path/to/your/python/script/TEMP/report.csv

If your temp folder or report.csv file do not exist, they will be created during the process.

After that you need to open the file, write to it, and close it. The following script can do that:

```
f = open(path,'wb')
f.write(report_downloader.DownloadReport(report))
f.close()
```

So you are basically running a download command directly into the open file and then closing it.

Hope this helps!

Aivoric

Comment: What you be able to give me the error? If you tried running this from the Python IDLE version 2.75 (instead of 2.76) then there might have been a bug related to the IDLE not been able to read the __file__ value within the code above.

Comment: The error I am getting is adspygoogle.adwords.AdWordsErrors.AdWordsReportError: HTTP code: 400, type: 'QuotaCheckError.INVALID_TOKEN_HEADER', trigger: 'myEmail@me.com', field path: '' But I have use OAuth 2.0 Process correctly.
and Sometimes
adspygoogle.common.Errors.MissingPackageError: PyXML v0.8.3 or newer is required.
Please help